# How to insert data in the database if the checkbox is checked?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, backend

I have a table in the database (absent) with the ID_Student and ID_Class that saves the absent students.

Below I've created the table with the student's names and every student is assigned to a checkbox.

I want to find a way so that I can insert into the absent table all student IDs that have been checked.

The code below doesn't work. I guess because of the $_POST array being inside the while loop? Is there an achievable way to make it work? Thank you!

```
<?php    
$sql = "SELECT ID_Student, first_name, last_name
            FROM student ;";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

 if($resultCheck > 0){
  $row_no = 1;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $id_std = $row['ID_Student'];
?>
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $row_no ?> </td>                    
<td>
  <label for = "customCheck + <?php echo $row_no?>"> <?php echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']; ?> </label>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name = "customCheck + <?php echo $row_no?>" id="customCheck + <?php echo $row_no?>" >
  </div>
</td>
</tr>    

<?php
if(isset($_POST["customCheck + <?php echo $row_no?>"])){    
  
  $sql = "INSERT INTO absent(ID_Student, ID_Class)
  VALUES($id_std, 3);";
  mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
$row_no ++;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What is `$_POST["customCheck + <?php echo $row_no?>"]`?

Comment: @Dharman it's the name of the checkbox type input.

Comment: That has to be the weirdest name I have ever seen. Do you realize that the `<?php echo` is a string literal and not php code?

Comment: @Dharman I apologize, i'm fairly new to PHP (3 days). But it worked so I went for it.

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: @Dharman I'm familiar with PDO but I was required to use mysqli

Comment: Why? Why would you want to use MySQLi only after 3 days of learning PHP? Either way, that is too advanced for you. Please open PHP manual and learn basics first. Research how strings work. Stack Overflow is not the right place for you at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

The code below shall run. But, it's very, VERY, awkward, and far from anything you would see in production. I'll not elaborate on that, sorry.

Please, look for an online bootcamp and/or a experienced friend before posting questions like this.

```
<?php    
    $sql = "
        SELECT ID_Student, first_name, last_name
        FROM student;";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($resultCheck > 0){
        $row_no = 1;
        
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $id_std = $row['ID_Student'];
?>
    <tr>
        <td> <?php echo $row_no ?> </td>                    
        <td>
            <label for = "customCheck_<?=$row_no?>">
                <?=$row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']?>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    class="custom-control-input"
                    name = "customCheck_<?=$row_no?>"
                    id="customCheck_<?=$row_no?>"
                >
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>    
<?php
            if(isset($_POST["customCheck_$row_no"])){
                $sql = "
                    INSERT INTO absent(ID_Student, ID_Class)
                    VALUES($id_std, 3);";
                    
                mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            }
            
            $row_no ++;
        }
    }
?>
```